# Split multiple columns by delimiter and create new rows after respective split events

Tags: postgresql, split

I have following table in Postgres

```
col1                               col2                     col3              col4
antiTB                             96165 | 96166            0.182 | 1         D12491 | D12492   
antiTB | antimaleria | antichol    96168 | 96169 | 96170    0.182 | 1 | 2     D12491 | D12492 | D12493
```

I would like to recursively split the column values by '|' and create new rows with values fetched after split.

The desired output is:

```
col1                               col2                     col3              col4
antiTB                             96165                    0.182             D12491
antiTB                             96166                    1                 D12492        
antiTB                             96168                    0.182             D12491
antimaleria                        96169                    1                 D12492    
antichol                           96170                    2                 D12493
```

I tried following query so far:

```
select distinct t2.col1, t3.col2, t4.col3, t5.col4
from table t1
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t1.col1,'|')) as t2 (col1)
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t1.col2,'|')) as t3 (col2)
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t1.col3,'|')) as t4 (col3)
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t1.col4,'|')) as t5 (col4)
;
```

The query is splitting column values but it is creating lot more rows in the output.
Any suggestion here would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `CROSS JOIN` which is going to create cartesian product. You'll want multiple [parallel `unnests` using `ROWS FROM` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) that are lateral to the `t1` selection. This can even be simplified by passing multiple arguments to `unnest`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT split.*
FROM t1,
LATERAL unnest(
  string_to_array(t1.col1,'|'),
  string_to_array(t1.col2,'|'),
  string_to_array(t1.col3,'|'),
  string_to_array(t1.col4,'|')
) AS split(col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

Comment: It works when there is a delimiter but when there is no delimiter, it creates a null value instead of copying the same value (as in first row: antiTB)

Comment: @rshar I didn't notice you had rows that had not always the same number of delimited values in each column. If there's only the case of single values, I guess [you can `coalesce` them to the original value](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6109543bbfa011af0ff405a0bd5b8654)